# How to fix dot as the decimal separator in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Got a tiny problem, but I can't get it right. Perhaps someone could help me out. Much appriciated.
my Regional Settings for Decimal Separator is "." (Dot).
i have an excel file, which contains decimals places in some columns. while updating the data in excel template i turned off the usersystem setting then applied DOT as the separator. While converting it to text file it is showing the comma "," as the decimal separator.
I am turning of the the user settings by using below code

> With Application
>       StrDecimal = .DecimalSeparator
>       StrThousand = .ThousandsSeparator

```
.DecimalSeparator = "."  
.ThousandsSeparator = "'" 
.UseSystemSeparators = False  
End With
```

Need to check if the Decimal Separator is not eqaul to "." then we need to force to use "." aS Decimal separator.

Please help how to achieve this by using VBA or by using Datavalidation
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hi All
please do a favour... Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've got your data and are writing it to a textfile.  Assuming your data is in an array, I'd loop through the array and convert the data after converting it to a string, like so.

```
Sub ChangeDecimalSeperator()
    Dim vData As Variant, ii As Integer, jj As Integer

    vData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2")
    For ii = LBound(vData, 1) To UBound(vData, 1)
        For jj = LBound(vData) To UBound(vData, 2)
            'Only convert if it's a number
            If VBA.IsNumeric(vData(ii, jj)) Then
                'You can also specify the format using VBA.Format$() here, ie force the decimal places
                vData(ii, jj) = ReplaceCharacter(VBA.CStr(vData(ii, jj)), ".", ",")
            End If
        Next jj
    Next ii

    'Now output vData to your textfile

End Sub


Function ReplaceCharacter(sForString As String, sReplacingCharacter As String, sWithCharacter As String) As String
    Dim sStringPrevious As String

    'While there is a character that we still need replacing left, keep going. If we can't find one, we're done
    Do
        sStringPrevious = sForString
        sForString = VBA.Replace(sForString, sReplacingCharacter, sWithCharacter)
    Loop Until sStringPrevious = sForString

    ReplaceCharacter = sForString
End Function
```

Comment: Thankyou CuberChase for you response. I am not importing text file. I am exporting the excel data into text file. with my code it will be able to display the decimal separator as ".", but when exporting to text file it uses the system decimal separator as ",". Ex. : 20,00 ("," comma is the decimal separator). i need to exort it as 20.00 (i.e. "." dot as the decimal separator)

Comment: Ok I see.  I've been playing around with the decimalseperator an it doesn't seem useful for your purposes.  So it depends how you are writing the data to the text file.  If it is being written to a text file then you have to convert your values to a string.  If that is the case, then I'd use a replace function.  I can't add the function in the comments so I'll edit my first answer.

Comment: Thank you so much CuberChase...  
the code useful to me.. i have utilized some part of the code to serve the purpose of mine.