# Changing decimal separator in Excel using a macro

Tags: excel, vba, decimal-point

I am using a simple java program that outputs data into several comma separated text files. I import these files to Excel using a macro pasting each file into separate sheets named after file name. The problem is that the output decimal separator is point "." and the regional setting is comma ",". I don't want to keep changing the regional settings all the time.

Using Ctrl+F and replacing all points with commas works fine. But if I record this as a macro and run it the data is displayed incorrectly and I get "number stored as text" errors (like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075968/using-the-replace-method-in-vba-leaves-numbers-stored-as-strings)). I have been looking at two possible solutions for this:

1. Using a replace function like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710548/how-to-fix-dot-as-the-decimal-separator-in-excel). But I have trouble getting it to run as I don't understand what some of the lines do and what I need to change.
2. Changing the comma separator settings in Excel like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252436/how-to-change-decimal-separator-with-macro). This solution would require these settings to reset on exit. Doing it this way does not really solve the problem but goes around it.

Example output [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=02417694133455788952). Thank you very much for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Open command in Excel you can open that, modify the advanced button in the screen **"Column Data Format"** (Step 3 of 3) and modify the import separator.
If you use a macro use the following:

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="E:\0\aa.TXT", Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1 _
    , DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
    , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), _
    DecimalSeparator:=".", ThousandsSeparator:="&", TrailingMinusNumbers:= _
    True
```

If you don't select the Thousands separator, you can have some strange value like 2.345 it's imported like 2345. (The same with open). If you use for example **&** separator for Thousands, you don't have the problem.

Comment: Added `.TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."` to my macro and it works like a charm. Thank you very much!