# Changing decimal separator in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've written simple code in VBA (and seen questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131805/changing-decimal-separator-in-vba-not-only-in-excel) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710548/how-to-fix-dot-as-the-decimal-separator-in-excel) and none of these solutions work).

```
            Dim toString As String
            toString = cell.Value & "_"
               If (InStr(toString, ",")) Then
                 toString = Replace(toString, ",", ".")
                 toString = Trim(toString)
                 cell.Value = " " + Left(toString, (Len(toString) - 1))               
               End If
```

Unfortunately, instead of string with dot separator, excel gives me double with comma in cell.Value. What curious is, when I exchange this whitespace with "_", it converts f. ex. 12,3 into _12.3. How can I fix it?

P.S. I add "_" at the end to ensure that toString will remain String.

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? `cell.Value = " " + Left(toString, (Len(toString) - 1)) `

Comment: @Andreas Firstly it looked so: `cell.Value = Left(toString, (Len(toString) -1))` but i found out that cell.Value changes into double so I tried to add a whitespace to convert it into string but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this issue before. You need to change the formatting of the cell before you write to it.

```
Application.Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A100").NumberFormat = "@"
```

After that line runs you can simply write to the column like this:

```
Cells(1,1).Value = "12.3"
```

Excel will keep the string formatting and not convert it to a double.

Hope this helps.